# Fast wired communication protocols

Tags: esp32, spi, communication

I have an esp32 connected to an FPGA about 2 cm on a PCB. I am trying to send a constant data stream to the FPGA at a throughput of around 1.5 MB/s.

This is too fast for UART, I've been considering SPI but I don't really know how I can implement it in the FPGA.

Are there any other fast data communication protocols over wires available to me, or even a parallel protocol ?

Comment: An SPI receiver-only port is little more than a shift register.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I will give SPI a go then, sounds like the most obvious choice

Comment: I believe there are wider SPI bus implementations.  Like 2 data lines or maybe even more.  Maybe that will give you more through put.  But do you need full-duplex?  I2C is half-duplex and uses fewer pins. But timing is more critical.  There is also an audio serial bus protocol.  Maybe you should look into that one.

Comment: @st2000 thanks, I am only using a half duplex set up, I very briefly looked at I2S but it seemed a little too slow, I may well have overlooked something. I think SPI may be the one.